# Using Filterable in Search Activity Android

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-filterable

I am getting no difference in results whereas they should be filtered as I type in the searchable view. Here is my code please help. This code runs but doesn't filter anything.

```
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            String sql="select history,rowid _id from search_history order by counter desc limit 5";
             final Cursor cursor = db.findCursor(sql,null);
            //TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView123);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 int[] columnTextId = new int[] {R.id.textView1};
                 SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter simple = new SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.text_view_for_suggestions, cursor,
                            columns , columnTextId
                            , 1);

                 simple.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                 simple.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    simple.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

                        @Override
                        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.v("Running","Yes");
                            return db.findCursor("select history,rowid _id from search_history", null);
                        }
                    });
                    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(simple);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[SOLVED]UPDATE:

```
        @Override
                        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.v("Running","Yes");
                            String x=constraint.toString();
                            return db.findCursor("select history,rowid _id from search_history where history LIKE '"+x+"%'", null);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: you don't use constraint at all in runQuery

Comment: i am unable to recognize how to use it.